# Where to find IPA transcriptions of Hochdeutsch online?

Tags: resource, pronunciation

Where can I find a comprehensive online resource for IPA transcriptions of the "official" pronunciation of German words?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[www.pons.eu](http://www.pons.eu/) has IPA transcriptions and sound clips for words.

For example, for the word [Familie](http://en.pons.eu/dict/search/results/?q=familie&in=&kbd=de&l=deen) that you mentioned, pons.eu says

> Fa·mi·lie <-, -n> [faˈmi:li̯ə] NOUN f

I think the sound clips are computer generated though, as opposed to being recorded by a native speaker.

Comment: Thanks! Pons has a lot of transcriptions, and seems more reliable than Wiktionary as I haven't found any errors.

Answer (score 8):

[Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aHauptseite) has some, and so does the [Duden](http://www.duden.de/). However, they are usually not present in dictionaries since German almost universally follows a fixed set of rules for pronunciation so there is generally no need to indicate it explicitly (except for loan words).

Comment: My german dictionary (paper) has the IPA transcription... Now, it doesn't really matter what rules a give language has, IPA is always useful because it's pretty much unambiguous. :P

Comment: I've always been afraid of general rules. @Alenanno: Mine only has it for some words.

Comment: I can't find any pronunciation help except for sound on Duden. Where is it? E.g [Familie](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Familie)

Comment: @Tim: As I said, not all words have pronunciation hints, only those where pronunciation isn’t obvious from the rules. Your example, “Familie”, merely has a stress hint: “Fami͟lie”. Other words do have IPA transcripts, e.g. [“Ketchup”](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ketchup): [ˈkɛt͜ʃap]