# Aussprache von 'Ordnung' - Ort? oder Ord?

Tags: pronunciation

Meine Damen und Herren,
eine Frage nach der Aussprache von 'd' vor einem anderen Konsonant.

Widmung [ˈvɪtmʊŋ]
Ordnung [ˈɔʁdnʊŋ]

Warum sind sie unterschiedlich?

In der Ausspracheregel steht:
*Am Wort und Silbenende werden b, d, g, s und v wie [p], [t], [k], [s] und [f] gesprochen*

Danach muss 't' das Richtige sein. Dann warum klingt 'd' in Ordnung wie 'd'?

Noch andere Frage:
In der Regel klingt 's' wie 'z' vor einem Vokal.

Nase [ˈnaːzə]
Sekunde [zeˈkʊndə]
Bremse [ˈbʀɛmzə]

Ich habe aber einige Ausnahmen gefunden, in denen 's' wie 's' klingt:
Erbse [ˈɛʁpsə]
Kekse [ˈkeːksə]

Meiner Meinung nach, scheint es von Vorderkonsonant beeinflusst zu sein.
Das heißt, -bse, -kse, -pse sind gleich. Aber was ist besonder mit 'b''k''p'? (sogenanntem 'Explosivlaut'?)

Ich habe trotzdem nie von solchen Regeln gehört, dass die Aussprache von 's' mit Vorderbuchstabe verbunden ist, besonders nur nach Explosivlaut.

Gibt es etwas andere Regeln dafür?
MfG, Stephan

Comment: Die zitierte Ausspracheregel stammt woher? Die andere Frage sollte separat sein. *In der Regel klingt...* ist nur Deine Beobachtung?

Comment: Die von dir zitierte Regel nennt man »Auslautverhärtung«. Sie wird aber nicht im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum angewendet. Je weiter du nach Süden kommst, desto weniger gültig ist diese Regel. In Österreich gibt es so gut wie keine Auslautverhärtung. Daher spricht man die Widmung in Ö nicht als [ˈvɪtmʊŋ], sondern als [ˈvɪdmʊŋ] aus.

Comment: Auch das stimmhafte s ([z]) wirst du in Österreich kaum hören (gilt für Sprecher über ca. 25 Jahren. Jüngere Sprecher verwenden es immer öfter). Bei den Ü25-Spechern klingt das S in Wiese und Nase gleich wie das S in mies oder in Glas.

Comment: Bitte nur eine Frage pro Post stellen.

Comment: Der Unterschied zwischen Widmung und Ordnung ist, dass die Zunge bei d und m nicht an der gleichen Stelle ist, aber bei d und n. Ich denke, dass es deshalb bei Ordnung zu einer Verschmelzung kommt und dadurch weicher wird.

Comment: Ich würde beides als t aussprechen, da ich zuerst norddeutsch geprägt wurde und dann immer weiter in den Süden ging. Ich halte das für die offizielle Aussprache in Deutschland, lasse mich aber belehren.

Comment: eine Regel: [When is the last sound of a syllable unvoiced?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/919)

Comment: @sumelic: Vielen Dank für Guten Tipp! Bestimmt stammt 'Handlung' aus 'handeln', aber 'Ordnung' ist nicht auf dieser Weise erklärbar, weil es aus 'ordnen' stammt, statt 'ordenen'. Warum klingt dann 'ordnen' als /d/?

Comment: Der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ordnen) sagt, dass die Etymologie des Wortes "ordnen" ist "mittelhochdeutsch ord**e**nen, althochdeutsch ordinōn < lateinisch ordinare, ordinieren"

Comment: @sumelic: Danke. Deutsch ist allgemein sehr regelmäßig(also mag ich es), aber in diesem Fall ist es ein bisschen unerwartet, dass die Aussprache nicht bloß von Buchstabe abhängig ist, und dass man sogar Etymologie(statt Infinitiv) vorher kennen muss. Außerdem gilt diese Regel nicht immer - z.B, 'Freunde' stammt aus 'Freund', aber es klingt wie /d/, statt /t/. (Gilt diese Regel nur für von Verb ableitetes Nomen?) Auf jeden Fall glaube ich es ist genug für 'Ordnung'.
Kann jemand bitte 'Erbse' erklären?

Answer (score 1):

## Aussprache von *Ordnung* und *Widmung*

Ich bin sehr skeptisch, was einen Unterschied in der Auslautverhärtung zwischen den Wörtern *Ordnung* und *Widmung* angeht.

1. Ich kann den Unterschied nicht beobachten, denn ich spreche Hochdeutsch ohne Auslautverhärtung.
2. Der Status der Auslautverhärtung ist sowieso zweifelhaft. Es handelt sich um eine präskriptive Regel aus dem späten 19. Jahrhundert, die kaum Beachtung gefunden hat, bis sie in den 1960ern von der generativen Grammatik entdeckt und zu der bekanntesten Aussprachregel des Deutschen emporstilisiert wurde.
3. Noch viel skeptischer bin ich bei der Behauptung, dass die Auslautverhärtung von der Etymologie abhängen soll. Wie sollte das denn funktionieren? Wie sollte ein Laut, der vor Jahrhunderten verschwunden ist, heute plötzlich die Aussprache beeinflussen?

   Viel wahrscheinlicher dünkt es mich, dass der Rückgriff auf die Etymologie eine blosse Verlegenheitslösung darstellt. Leute sind verunsichert, denn sie haben keine Auslautverhärtung, obwohl doch die Regel der Auslautverhärtung so bekannt ist (seit den 1960ern). Also erfinden sie komplizierte Erklärungen, um diesen Gegensatz aufzulösen. Dabei ist die Erklärung trivial: Sie haben keine Auslautverhärtung.

Eine plausible Erklärung dafür, dass das *d* in *Widmung* verschärft wie ein *t* ausgesprochen würde, sehe ich in der deutschen Silbenstruktur. Ein kurzer Vokal wie das *i* in *Widmung* darf nie am Ende einer Silbe stehen, sondern muss von einem Konsonanten gefolgt werden. Dabei sind nicht beliebige Folgekonsonanten möglich. Einfaches /b d ɡ/ sind als Folgekonsonanten ausgeschlossen. Erlaubt sind hingegen (neben anderen Konsonanten) einfaches /p t k/:

- *Kurzer Vokal* + einfaches /t/ ist eine geläufige Kombination, z.B. in *Schnitt, statt, Gott, fett* usw.
- *Kurzer Vokal* + einfaches /d/ kommt nicht vor ausser in Einzelfällen wie *Widmung* oder gelegentlich in Fremdwörtern wie *Grid.*

Also scheint es gut möglich, dass *Widmung* in Analogie zu den anderen Wörtern mit scharfem /t/ ausgesprochen wird.

Im Wort *Ordnung* hat ebenfalls einen kurzen Vokal, aber der Folgekonsonant ist kein einfacher Verschlusslaut, sondern eine Kombination aus Sonorant (die stimmhaften Laute /r l n m/) + Verschlusslaut wie in *Mord, Erfolg, Rand.* Es gibt also keinen Analogiegrund, um das *d* in *Ordnung* verschärft auszusprechen.

## Aussprache von *Erbse*

Die Aussprache von Wörtern wie *Erbse* lässt sich viel besser erklären, wenn man die Stimmhaftigkeit nicht als primäres Merkmal des deutschen /z/ auf‌fasst:

1. Die weichen Obstruenten des Deutschen (/z/ sowie /b d ɡ/) sind stimmlos.
2. Die weichen Obstruenten des Deutschen können stimmhaft werden, wenn sie keinen stimmlosen Laut berühren.

Im Wort *Erbse* berührt das /z/ ein stimmloses /b/ – also kann es nicht stimmhaft werden.

Diese Erklärung hat den Vorteil, dass sie für den gesamten deutschen Sprachraum anwendbar ist. Wenn man nämlich die Stimmhaftigkeit als primäres Merkmal annimmt, dann muss man erklären, warum überall ausser im Norden die Stimmhaftigkeit verschwindet.

Comment: Als Anfänger von Deutsch(besonders ohne viel Linguistikserkenntnis), war diese Erklärung sicher ein bisschen schwer:)
Ein überraschender Punkt davon ist "1.Ich kann den Unterschied nicht beobachten, denn ich spreche Hochdeutsch ohne Auslautverhärtung", denn ich habe mich bisher nur auf Wörterbuch verlassen.
In der Tat, habe ich ein Paar Deutsche gefragt nach Aussprache von 'Lindner'. Die Folge? Beides - /d/ und /t/. Nun habe ich das Gefühl(oder Angst) dass es keine solche 'absolute Regelung' dafür gibt.
Danke schön immerhin für ausführliche Antwort.

Comment: @Stephan: durch die vielen Antworten, die nur Kommentare sind, hat das System deine Frage nun auf "protected" gesetzt. Bitte nimm dir Zeit für die [tour], um unsere Seite und wie wir funktionieren kennen zu lernen. Wenn Du angemeldet bist (das ist völlig kostenlos!), kannst du auch eine für die richtige Antwort als solche "akzeptieren", der Antwortende erhält dafür Punkte. Das ist die S.E.-Art Danke zu sagen.

Comment: Deine sehr plausiblen Gedanken werfen ein ganz neues Licht auf die Auslautverhärtung, die ich ohnehin immer schon kritisch beäugt habe. Vielen Dank für diese Antwort!